# Android many textviews align side by side in linearlayout or relativelayout

Tags: android, css, xml, android-layout

I am new in Android and I try to formatting Quran page content. It is word by word textview. I have to show it side by side align right.

Please suggest me how to display it side by side

Style Format

```
<style name="WordStyle" >
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
</style>
<style name="AyaStyle">
    <item name="android:textColor">#008866</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
</style>
```

XML Format

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:textDirection="rtl"
tools:context="info.studyquran.project.study.MainActivity">

<TextView 
    android:tag="2:6:1" 
    style="@style/WordStyle" 
    android:onClick="onWord" 
    android:text="إِنَّ " 
    />
<TextView 
    android:tag="2:6:2" 
    style="@style/WordStyle" 
    android:onClick="onWord" 
    android:text="ٱلَّذِينَ " 
    />
<TextView 
    android:tag="2:6:3" 
    style="@style/WordStyle" 
    android:onClick="onWord" 
    android:text="كَفَرُوا۟ " 
    />
<TextView 
    android:tag="2:6:4" 
    style="@style/WordStyle" 
    android:onClick="onWord" 
    android:text="سَوَآءٌ " 
    />
<TextView 
    android:tag="2:6:5" 
    style="@style/WordStyle" 
    android:onClick="onWord" 
    android:text="عَلَيْهِمْ " 
    />
<TextView 
    android:tag="2:6:6" 
    style="@style/WordStyle" 
    android:onClick="onWord" 
    android:text="ءَأَنذَرْتَهُمْ " 
    />
<TextView 
    android:tag="2:6:7" 
    style="@style/WordStyle" 
    android:onClick="onWord" 
    android:text="أَمْ " 
    />
<TextView 
    android:tag="2:6:8" 
    style="@style/WordStyle" 
    android:onClick="onWord" 
    android:text="لَمْ " 
    />
<TextView 
    android:tag="2:6:9" 
    style="@style/WordStyle" 
    android:onClick="onWord" 
    android:text="تُنذِرْهُمْ " 
    />
<TextView 
    android:tag="2:6:10" 
    style="@style/WordStyle" 
    android:onClick="onWord" 
    android:text="لَا " 
    />
<TextView 
    android:tag="2:6:11" 
    style="@style/WordStyle" 
    android:onClick="onWord" 
    android:text="يُؤْمِنُونَ " 
    />
<TextView 
    style="@style/AyaStyle" 
    android:tag="2:6" 
    android:onClick="onAya" 
    android:text=" ﴿٦﴾ " 
    />
<TextView android:tag="2:7:1" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="خَتَمَ " /><TextView android:tag="2:7:2" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="ٱللَّهُ " /><TextView android:tag="2:7:3" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="عَلَىٰ " /><TextView android:tag="2:7:4" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="قُلُوبِهِمْ " /><TextView android:tag="2:7:5" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="وَعَلَىٰ " /><TextView android:tag="2:7:6" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="سَمْعِهِمْ " /><TextView android:tag="2:7:7" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="وَعَلَىٰٓ " /><TextView android:tag="2:7:8" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="أَبْصَٰرِهِمْ " /><TextView android:tag="2:7:9" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="غِشَٰوَةٌ " /><TextView android:tag="2:7:10" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="وَلَهُمْ " /><TextView android:tag="2:7:11" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="عَذَابٌ " /><TextView android:tag="2:7:12" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="عَظِيمٌ " /><TextView style="@style/AyaStyle" android:tag="2:7" android:onClick="onAya" android:text=" ﴿٧﴾ " />
<TextView android:tag="2:8:1" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="وَمِنَ " /><TextView android:tag="2:8:2" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="ٱلنَّاسِ " /><TextView android:tag="2:8:3" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="مَن " /><TextView android:tag="2:8:4" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="يَقُولُ " /><TextView android:tag="2:8:5" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="ءَامَنَّا " /><TextView android:tag="2:8:6" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="بِٱللَّهِ " /><TextView android:tag="2:8:7" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="وَبِٱلْيَوْمِ " /><TextView android:tag="2:8:8" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="ٱلْءَاخِرِ " /><TextView android:tag="2:8:9" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="وَمَا " /><TextView android:tag="2:8:10" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="هُم " /><TextView android:tag="2:8:11" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="بِمُؤْمِنِينَ " /><TextView style="@style/AyaStyle" android:tag="2:8" android:onClick="onAya" android:text=" ﴿٨﴾ " />
<TextView android:tag="2:9:1" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="يُخَٰدِعُونَ " /><TextView android:tag="2:9:2" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="ٱللَّهَ " /><TextView android:tag="2:9:3" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="وَٱلَّذِينَ " /><TextView android:tag="2:9:4" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="ءَامَنُوا۟ " /><TextView android:tag="2:9:5" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="وَمَا " /><TextView android:tag="2:9:6" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="يَخْدَعُونَ " /><TextView android:tag="2:9:7" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="إِلَّآ " /><TextView android:tag="2:9:8" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="أَنفُسَهُمْ " /><TextView android:tag="2:9:9" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="وَمَا " /><TextView android:tag="2:9:10" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="يَشْعُرُونَ " /><TextView style="@style/AyaStyle" android:tag="2:9" android:onClick="onAya" android:text=" ﴿٩﴾ " />
<TextView android:tag="2:10:1" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="فِى " /><TextView android:tag="2:10:2" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="قُلُوبِهِم " /><TextView android:tag="2:10:3" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="مَّرَضٌ " /><TextView android:tag="2:10:4" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="فَزَادَهُمُ " /><TextView android:tag="2:10:5" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="ٱللَّهُ " /><TextView android:tag="2:10:6" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="مَرَضًا " /><TextView android:tag="2:10:7" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="وَلَهُمْ " /><TextView android:tag="2:10:8" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="عَذَابٌ " /><TextView android:tag="2:10:9" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="أَلِيمٌۢ " /><TextView android:tag="2:10:10" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="بِمَا " /><TextView android:tag="2:10:11" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="كَانُوا۟ " /><TextView android:tag="2:10:12" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="يَكْذِبُونَ " /><TextView style="@style/AyaStyle" android:tag="2:10" android:onClick="onAya" android:text=" ﴿١٠﴾ " />
<TextView android:tag="2:11:1" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="وَإِذَا " /><TextView android:tag="2:11:2" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="قِيلَ " /><TextView android:tag="2:11:3" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="لَهُمْ " /><TextView android:tag="2:11:4" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="لَا " /><TextView android:tag="2:11:5" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="تُفْسِدُوا۟ " /><TextView android:tag="2:11:6" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="فِى " /><TextView android:tag="2:11:7" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="ٱلْأَرْضِ " /><TextView android:tag="2:11:8" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="قَالُوٓا۟ " /><TextView android:tag="2:11:9" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="إِنَّمَا " /><TextView android:tag="2:11:10" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="نَحْنُ " /><TextView android:tag="2:11:11" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="مُصْلِحُونَ " /><TextView style="@style/AyaStyle" android:tag="2:11" android:onClick="onAya" android:text=" ﴿١١﴾ " />
<TextView android:tag="2:12:1" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="أَلَآ " /><TextView android:tag="2:12:2" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="إِنَّهُمْ " /><TextView android:tag="2:12:3" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="هُمُ " /><TextView android:tag="2:12:4" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="ٱلْمُفْسِدُونَ " /><TextView android:tag="2:12:5" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="وَلَٰكِن " /><TextView android:tag="2:12:6" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="لَّا " /><TextView android:tag="2:12:7" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="يَشْعُرُونَ " /><TextView style="@style/AyaStyle" android:tag="2:12" android:onClick="onAya" android:text=" ﴿١٢﴾ " />
<TextView android:tag="2:13:1" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="وَإِذَا " /><TextView android:tag="2:13:2" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="قِيلَ " /><TextView android:tag="2:13:3" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="لَهُمْ " /><TextView android:tag="2:13:4" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="ءَامِنُوا۟ " /><TextView android:tag="2:13:5" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="كَمَآ " /><TextView android:tag="2:13:6" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="ءَامَنَ " /><TextView android:tag="2:13:7" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="ٱلنَّاسُ " /><TextView android:tag="2:13:8" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="قَالُوٓا۟ " /><TextView android:tag="2:13:9" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="أَنُؤْمِنُ " /><TextView android:tag="2:13:10" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="كَمَآ " /><TextView android:tag="2:13:11" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="ءَامَنَ " /><TextView android:tag="2:13:12" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="ٱلسُّفَهَآءُ " /><TextView android:tag="2:13:13" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="أَلَآ " /><TextView android:tag="2:13:14" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="إِنَّهُمْ " /><TextView android:tag="2:13:15" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="هُمُ " /><TextView android:tag="2:13:16" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="ٱلسُّفَهَآءُ " /><TextView android:tag="2:13:17" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="وَلَٰكِن " /><TextView android:tag="2:13:18" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="لَّا " /><TextView android:tag="2:13:19" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="يَعْلَمُونَ " /><TextView style="@style/AyaStyle" android:tag="2:13" android:onClick="onAya" android:text=" ﴿١٣﴾ " />
<TextView android:tag="2:14:1" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="وَإِذَا " /><TextView android:tag="2:14:2" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="لَقُوا۟ " /><TextView android:tag="2:14:3" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="ٱلَّذِينَ " /><TextView android:tag="2:14:4" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="ءَامَنُوا۟ " /><TextView android:tag="2:14:5" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="قَالُوٓا۟ " /><TextView android:tag="2:14:6" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="ءَامَنَّا " /><TextView android:tag="2:14:7" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="وَإِذَا " /><TextView android:tag="2:14:8" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="خَلَوْا۟ " /><TextView android:tag="2:14:9" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="إِلَىٰ " /><TextView android:tag="2:14:10" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="شَيَٰطِينِهِمْ " /><TextView android:tag="2:14:11" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="قَالُوٓا۟ " /><TextView android:tag="2:14:12" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="إِنَّا " /><TextView android:tag="2:14:13" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="مَعَكُمْ " /><TextView android:tag="2:14:14" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="إِنَّمَا " /><TextView android:tag="2:14:15" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="نَحْنُ " /><TextView android:tag="2:14:16" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="مُسْتَهْزِءُونَ " /><TextView style="@style/AyaStyle" android:tag="2:14" android:onClick="onAya" android:text=" ﴿١٤﴾ " />
<TextView android:tag="2:15:1" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="ٱللَّهُ " /><TextView android:tag="2:15:2" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="يَسْتَهْزِئُ " /><TextView android:tag="2:15:3" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="بِهِمْ " /><TextView android:tag="2:15:4" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="وَيَمُدُّهُمْ " /><TextView android:tag="2:15:5" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="فِى " /><TextView android:tag="2:15:6" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="طُغْيَٰنِهِمْ " /><TextView android:tag="2:15:7" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="يَعْمَهُونَ " /><TextView style="@style/AyaStyle" android:tag="2:15" android:onClick="onAya" android:text=" ﴿١٥﴾ " />
<TextView android:tag="2:16:1" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="أُو۟لَٰٓئِكَ " /><TextView android:tag="2:16:2" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="ٱلَّذِينَ " /><TextView android:tag="2:16:3" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="ٱشْتَرَوُا۟ " /><TextView android:tag="2:16:4" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="ٱلضَّلَٰلَةَ " /><TextView android:tag="2:16:5" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="بِٱلْهُدَىٰ " /><TextView android:tag="2:16:6" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="فَمَا " /><TextView android:tag="2:16:7" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="رَبِحَت " /><TextView android:tag="2:16:8" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="تِّجَٰرَتُهُمْ " /><TextView android:tag="2:16:9" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="وَمَا " /><TextView android:tag="2:16:10" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="كَانُوا۟ " /><TextView android:tag="2:16:11" style="@style/WordStyle" android:onClick="onWord" android:text="مُهْتَدِينَ " /><TextView style="@style/AyaStyle" android:tag="2:16" android:onClick="onAya" android:text=" ﴿١٦﴾ " />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay you can use grid View in this case..
Here's how you can do this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:columnWidth="100dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

</GridView>
```

Create a separate items.xml

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/grid_item_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@+id/label"
    android:layout_marginTop="5px"
    android:textSize="15px" >
</TextView>
```

set a custom adapter something like this

```
public class TextViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context context;
        private final String[] textViewValues;

        public TextViewAdapter(Context context, String[] textViewValues) {
            this.context = context;
            this.textViewValues = textViewValues;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View gridView;

            if (convertView == null) {

                gridView = new View(context);

                // get layout from mobile.xml
                gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);

                // set value into textview
                TextView textView = (TextView) gridView
                        .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label);
                textView.setText(textViewValues[position]);  
            } else {
                gridView = (View) convertView;
            }

            return gridView;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return textViewValues.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

    }
```

and then , finally set adapter in your main class

```
gridView.setAdapter(new TextViewAdapter(this, YourArrayofText));
```

Comment: thanks for your response it is display only top line other line hidden http://www.artesemgeral.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/second.png

Comment: It is more than 110 textview, check i update xml code

Comment: Approve my answer if u got your answer @user2105386

Answer (score 0):

Just add android:gravity="right" in the LinearLayout like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:textDirection="rtl"
tools:context="info.studyquran.project.study.MainActivity"
android:gravity="right">
```

Comment: thanks for your response, yes it is align right but not side by side. display like this http://www.artesemgeral.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/first.png

Answer (score 0):

In Linear Layout

**change**

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

**to**

```
android:orientation="horizontal"
```

Comment: thanks for your response but is not side by side . it is display like this http://www.artesemgeral.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/first.png